# Change class on multiple img in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, addclass, removeclass

This is my first post here, I always found solutions on this page, so thank you for that.

I have a problem with `.removeClass` and `.addClass` in my last program.
I load multiple pictures into array `Frames` and I want change all (`previous-image`) to (`current-image`) in `frames[0]`. Here is my code, it is change class only on second image. Here is code:

```
function loadImage() {
  // Creates a new <li>
  var li = document.createElement("li");
  // Generates the image file name using the incremented "loadedImages" variable
  var imageName = "graphics/img/Dodge_Viper_SRT10_2010_360_720_50-" + (loadedImages + 1) + ".jpg";
  var imageName1 = "graphics/img/Dodge_Viper_SRT10_2010_360_720_50-" + (loadedImages + 1) + ".jpg";
  /*
                Creates a new <img> and sets its src attribute to point to the file name we generated.
                It also hides the image by applying the "previous-image" CSS class to it.
                The image then is added to the <li>.
            */

  var image = $('<img>').attr('src', imageName).addClass("previous-image").appendTo(li) && $('<img>').attr('src', imageName1).addClass("previous-image light-image").appendTo(li);

  // We add the newly added image object (returned by jQuery) to the "frames" array.
  frames.push(image);
  // We add the <li> to the <ol>
  $images.append(li);

  /*
                Adds the "load" event handler to the new image.
                When the event triggers it calls the "imageLoaded" function.
            */
  $(image).load(function() {
    imageLoaded();
  });
};

function imageLoaded() {
  // Increments the value of the "loadedImages" variable
  loadedImages++;
  // Updates the preloader percentage text
  $("#spinner span").text(Math.floor(loadedImages / totalFrames * 100) + "%");
  // Checks if the currently loaded image is the last one in the sequence...
  if (loadedImages == totalFrames) {
    // ...if so, it makes the first image in the sequence to be visible by removing the "previous-image" class and applying the "current-image" on it
    frames[0].removeClass("previous-image").addClass("current-image");
    /*
                    Displays the image slider by using the jQuery "fadeOut" animation and its complete event handler.
                    When the preloader is completely faded, it stops the preloader rendering and calls the "showThreesixty" function to display the images.
                */
    $("#spinner").fadeOut("slow", function() {
      spinner.hide();
      showThreesixty();
    });
  } else {
    // ...if not, Loads the next image in the sequence
    loadImage();
  }
};
```

This is, how it looks in browser:

```
<ol><li><img src="graphics/img/Dodge_Viper_SRT10_2010_360_720_50-1.jpg" class="previous-image"><img src="graphics/img/Dodge_Viper_SRT10_2010_360_720_50-1.jpg" class="light-image current-image"></li></ol>
```

This is, what I want:

```
<ol><li><img src="graphics/img/Dodge_Viper_SRT10_2010_360_720_50-1.jpg" class="current-image"><img src="graphics/img/Dodge_Viper_SRT10_2010_360_720_50-1.jpg" class="light-image current-image"></li></ol>
```

When I change this

```
var image = $('<img>').attr('src', imageName).addClass("previous-image").appendTo(li) && $('<img>').attr('src', imageName1).addClass("previous-image light-image").appendTo(li);
```

to this

```
var image = $('<img>').attr('src', imageName1).addClass("previous-image light-image").appendTo(li) && $('<img>').attr('src', imageName).addClass("previous-image").appendTo(li);
```

it still change only second img. Any help?

Comment: Using `frames[0]`, you are only targeting first array item. But you say it works only on second one. I have hard time to get the logic behind your code. IMHO, you should provide MCVE(jsFiddle?) to make it clearer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var image = $('<img>').attr('src', imageName).addClass("previous-image").appendTo(li) && $('<img>').attr('src', imageName1).addClass("previous-image light-image").appendTo(li);
```

is not doing what you think it is. It's only using the second element you declare. They both get appended to the page (because the appendTo method runs), but && is a logical operator, it's not used for concatenation, so the variable "image" only contains the second image you declared.

This will work instead:

```
var image = $('<img>', { "src": imageName, "class": "previous-image" });
image = image.add($('<img>', { "src": imageName1, "class": "previous-image light-image" }));
image.appendTo(li);
```

Comment: Thanks, thats exactly what I need :) Work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just trying to replace all the previous-image classes with current image then you can do this:

```
$('img.previous-image').each(function(){
   $(this).addClass("current-image").removeClass("previous-image");
});
```